IDA and hex editor different values
Initially I have in IDA value in hex:
0003EF9B  A1 DC F3 12 00

But the I looked in hex editor same offset and its different:
A1-DC-F3-06-00

But it is half problem.
In hex editor I trying change the values:
0003EF9B  A1 DC F3 12 00

to:
B8 80 02 00 00

(i.e. I need load to eax value 0x280)
After editing in hex editor, I opened corrected file in IDA, and have difference:
0003EF9B  B8 DC F3 12 00

Where 0003EF9B its address in IDA.
I.e. same values (same address) is different in hex editor and IDA.
Its ms dos code and uses dos4gw. Program run under dosbox.
Why there is difference?
UPDATED
1)BEFORE changes
Before I made changes in hex editor:
https://i.ibb.co/gjRxW9g/hex1.jpg
Before I made changes in IDA (disassembled view):
https://i.ibb.co/qxVhZrN/ida11.jpg
Before I made changes in IDA (hex view):
https://i.ibb.co/Qp0qc8M/ida12.jpg
2)AFTER changes
After I made changes in hex editor:
https://i.ibb.co/NVCd34M/hex2.jpg
After I made changes in IDA (disassembled view):
https://i.ibb.co/TYytDjL/ida21.jpg
After I made changes in IDA (hex view):
https://i.ibb.co/zJ1fcNK/ida22.jpg

You are probably looking at different addresses............. have you considered the section alignment versus page alignment  differences into account  ..... Have you checked if all prior and post bytes match  apart from these 5 bytes...... .......if the address is correct in  both. And relocations are accounted for then the bytes MUST be same

Which version of IDA do you use? If you want to modify a binary you can do that directly in IDA, no need to use an external hex editor.

UPDATED question - added screenshots before and after changes.

In the hexeditor 1st screen shot address is 3xxxxx and in after change address is 5ddxxx. So you mean to say both are same

Sorry, on second screenshot hex2.jpg I made changes but not pressed F9 (update code). Now on hex2.jpg right view.

Do you work with LE executable (for exampe, DOS4GW extender used this format). If so, the bytes could be changed by IDA (and dos4gw when it loads application) according to fixup table. More info in documention for LE format, like here: http://www.edm2.com/index.php/LX_-_Linear_eXecutable_Module_Format_Description

Yes, its LE executable file. What can I todo to right correct this LE EXE in Hex editor?

I think, you should edit Fixups Record Table. For you task you probably should remove one entry from it.
As for you second IDA screenshots - did you created new IDA database after editing file in hex-editor? As long as I know IDA will not automatically reflect changes - it creates database and later works only with it, you can even delete source EXE file - no problem for IDA.

Yes, I created new IDA database after editing in hex-editor. And itself this EXE runs wrong, works wrong after ediing in hex-editor. I started this EXE after editing in hex-editor, and EXE shows not that I expected.
